# Var keyword type inference ambiguity when both interface and implementation are present

Tags: c#

Take this example:

```
interface IEntity {
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Product : IEntity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; } // added member
}

class Client {
    void Process() {
        var product = new Product();
        int count = product.Count; // this is valid            

    }
}
```

In the example above, what is the type of product? Is it IEntity or Product? It appears that product is of type concrete implementation (Product). If that is the case, shouldn't var be used only in special circumstances. But I see that tools like resharper recommend using var by default. Shouldn't one program to an interface?

Answer (score 7):

You are not actually "programming to interfaces" if you are still instantiating the concrete class within the method, as the dependency to the concrete Product class still remains. In order to properly program-to-interfaces you must remove the *new* instantiation, for example by using a factory or IoC.

Answer (score 6):

What if you had a Product like ...

```
class Product : IFirst, ISecond, IThrid
```

The only rational thing the complier can do is what it does.  I don't limit my use of `var`, I use it everywhere.  I think it makes code far more readable.  In this case, I agree with ReSharper across the board.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `Product` to be of type `IEntity`, try this:

```
var product = new Product() as IEntity;
```

That said, yes you should program to an interface, but in your case you're instantiating the concrete type directly. If you've already created a dependency to the concrete type, just use the concrete type. If not, use a factory or injection to get an instance of the interface. `var` will work with those rather well. For example:

```
public class MyExtremelySimpleFactoryExampleClass
{
  public IEntity Instantiate()
  {
    return new Product();
  }
}

// elsewhere in your code...
var item = myFactory.Instantiate(); // item is of type IEntity
```

Finally, no, I don't think `var` should be used only in "special circumstances". I find it quite useful and use it almost always.

Comment: as is used for casting without exception.  It should be                                 var product = (IEntity)new Product();

Answer (score 1):

`var product = new Product()` is of type `Product`.  You could program to the interface if you weren't using members outside that interface (`Product.Count` isn't on the `IEntity` interface).

**Added:**

Also, in VS2008, you can hover over the `var` keyword in the declaration to see the implied type.  This hover/tooltip message also works on the variable name after the declaration line.   (from [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), page 211)

Comment: The point is, the variable "product" will always default to type of "Product" (rather that IEntity) regardless of whether the implemented class (Product) has any extra members, when one uses var.

Comment: You could make an `IProduct` interface that includes the members that `Product` adds.

Answer (score 1):

The type that is inferred is the actual type, not any interface or base class that it may implement/inherit.

Consider this:

```
var answer = "42";
```

If it would infer an interface rather than the type, the variable type would be something like `IComparable` instead of `string`.

The usage of the `var` keyword relies on it inferring the actual type, or it would not make sense to use it for anything other than anonymous types. As long as the type is obvious you can use it to make the code more readable, but if the type is not completely obvious, you should avoid using it. (My example above is in the gray area, as it does not actually contain the `string` type name.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `var` in this instance, it will be of type `Product`.  I don't like using `var` by default, as it can make reading code a little confusing at times.

I prefer using `var` mostly in `LINQ` queries, but try not to overuse it in other places (like your example).  For people using an IDE with intellisense it is fine, but if you are ever reading the code with Notepad (or Notepad++, etc.), you will have a harder time figuring out the type without a little research.

Comment: That is my point as well. Infact, in my example, this is the only way to program to the interface.

Comment: So yeah, as I said, I wouldn't use it in that circumstances. I use it mostly just for LINQ queries.